# Creating a list of valid constructors

Tags: haskell, gadt

Consider the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data T = T1 | T2

data D (t :: T) where
  D1 :: D T1
  D2 :: D T2
  D3 :: D d
  D4 :: D T1

x1 :: [D T1]
x1 = [D1, D3, D4]

x2 :: [D T2]
x2 = [D2, D3]
```

Basically `x1` is the list of all valid constructors for `D T1`, and `x2` is the list of all valid constructors for `D T2`.

However, I want both this lists to reflect any additional constructors added to `D`, I don't want to hard code these lists like they are currently.

Is there a way to define `x1` and `x2` such that they are automatically generated from `D`?

Comment: What you want can be achieved with `TemplateHaskell` or _generic programming_. Though exact functions require some time to write up. So maybe one who answers this question will give you exact functions.

Comment: You can't do such a thing, or your generated type would be infinite (and hence not a valid type). In particular, why would the lists `[D3] :: [D Any]`, `[D3] :: [D (Any Any)]`, not be generated?

Comment: .... Perhaps you want such an output from an input like `(D, [T1,T2])` (where you specify the types to check), or you want to assuming that there are actually closed kinds (they aren't!) - you are still in a bad position to achieve what you want, at least in this example. The reason is you must perform unification between `forall d . D d` and `D X` (where X is whatever type) - and only the GHC api (which isn't easy to use, to say the least) provides access to the GHC type unification algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer - my TemplateHaskell-fu is almost non-existent - but I've investigated a bit which should give you a starting point to work with:

For those who don't know Template Haskell is a kind of meta-programming (language) that allows to write programs that run at compile time - it is type checked so it is safe (for some definition of safe, I think you can write programs that take infinite time to compile).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Language.Haskell.TH

data T = T1 | T2

data D (t :: T) where
  D1 :: D T1
  D2 :: D T2
  D3 :: D d
  D4 :: D T1
```

You can start by loading the file into GHCi (don't forget to `:set -XTemplateHaskell` there)

```
> typeInfo = reify ''D
> $(stringE . show =<< typeInfo)
```

`typeInfo` is a `Q Info` that allows you to extract information from a type (escaped by `''`) - the `$(..)` works like print.

This gives you the template haskell Expression that constructs your (G)ADT:

```
TyConI (
    DataD [] TMP.D [KindedTV t_6989586621679027167 (ConT TMP.T)] Nothing 
        [GadtC [TMP.D1] [] (AppT (ConT TMP.D) (ConT TMP.T1))
        ,GadtC [TMP.D2] [] (AppT (ConT TMP.D) (ConT TMP.T2))
        ,ForallC [KindedTV d_6989586621679027168 (ConT TMP.T)] [] (GadtC [TMP.D3] [] (AppT (ConT TMP.D) (VarT d_6989586621679027168)))
        ,GadtC [TMP.D4] [] (AppT (ConT TMP.D) (ConT TMP.T1))] [])
```

I with a bit of pattern matching - you can find the constructors that have either no restriction (`ForallC`) or a certain type (`TMP.T1`/`TMP.T2`) and then write some expression - to create a new type from those.

Right now I don't have enough time to supply that - but I will update this answer tonight.

### EDIT

I looked some more at constructing types, but I have to admit I am a bit stuck myself - I deconstructed the type info kind of successfully.

```
d = reify ''D

dataName :: Info -> Maybe [Name]
dataName (TyConI (DataD _ _ _ _ x _) )= Just [t | NormalC t _ <- x]
dataName _ = Nothing

gadtDataUnsafe :: Info -> Q Exp
gadtDataUnsafe (TyConI (DataD _ _ _ _ cons _)) = return $ head $ concat [t | GadtC t _ _ <- cons]
```

I think it is doable to filter the `T1`/`T2`/`forall d` from here, tedious but doable to construct the lists.

What I failed at, is constructing the type - if I load the file into ghci I can execute

```
> f = $(gadtDataUnsafe =<< d)
>:t f
f :: D 'T1
```

but if I call that within the file I get the following error

```
error:
    • GHC stage restriction:
        ‘gadtData’ is used in a top-level splice, quasi-quote, or annotation,
        and must be imported, not defined locally
    • In the untyped splice: $(gadtData =<< d)
```

I know that for example Edward Kmett makes some th-magic creating lenses for stuff and there it works inside the same file, but the splice is not assigned to a variable - so maybe you need to construct the names for your lists inside the `Q Exp` - I guess `mkName` would be something you need there.

This concludes everything I found out - I hope it helps, I at least learnt a few things - for a full answer maybe someone smarter/more experienced with template haskell can supply some of his/her knowledge in a second answer.

Comment: Did you accidentally post your answer too soon?

Comment: Yes - I posted it accidentally a bit too early

Comment: Which GHC version do you use? I get a completely other output in 7.10. There, all non-restricted are `NormalC`, and the `GadtC` is `ForAllC ...`.

Comment: My GHC is `8.0.2` and [template-haskell 2.11.1.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.1.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html)

Comment: I'll have a look at that as well tonight

Comment: You are understandably 'stuck' - you must perform type unification to solve this problem, and TH does not provide any access to the type unification algorithm used by GHC. (Also, re: " if I call that within the file .." - yes, that's just how TH works! you need to split definitions and uses of meta-programs into different files)